# Storm-Kafka on CDH 5.11 with Kerberos security enabled

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kerberos, cloudera-cdh

I have installed Apache Storm 1.1.0 manually on CDH 5.11 cluster. This cluster is secured with Kerberos. 
I have storm sample written which ingest data from kafka topic and inserts into HDFS directory in real time. So, this sample uses storm-kafka as well as storm-hdfs. 
When I run the storm topology it gives the following error in kafka-spout.

```
==> 2017-06-18 22:29:31.297 o.a.z.ClientCnxn Thread-14-kafka-spout-executor[5 5]-SendThread(localhost:2181) [INFO] Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)


==> 2017-06-18 22:29:31.571 k.c.SimpleConsumer Thread-14-kafka-spout-executor[5 5] [INFO] Reconnect due to error:
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:85) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:83) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:149) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:75) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:65) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:94) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:129) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4976$fn__4991$fn__5022.invoke(executor.clj:644) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
```

Kafka version: 2.1.1-1.2.1.1.p0.18

There is no storm-kafka*.jat present in - "/usr/local/storm"
But this sample was working fine before kerberizing the cluster, even in this case.

I have tried the same example on Hortonworks and after adding the below code to set security protocol, the topology runs fine:

```
spoutConfig.securityProtocol = "SASL_PLAINTEXT";
```

After adding above code in case of Cloudera it gives error: "Symbol not found"

Please let me know if you need any other information...

Thanks in advance..